How to write SOQL query to get accounts where billing city equals to shipping city in single query?
This question asked in interview. As per my knowledge, it's not possible to get in single query. Is it even possible?
If yes, then how? Please answer this question.
Thank You!

Here's what Salesforce says about that. Does this answer your question?

If the two fields are on the same record, this is approached by using a custom Checkbox formula field to do the comparison, then querying using that Checkbox field. E.g. the field might be Same_City__c and have a formula:
BillingCity == ShippingCity

You would then do:
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Same_City__c == TRUE

Similar can be done with cross-object formula fields as long as there is a direct relationship and the formula field is on the child record.

Shakespeare wrote "Horse a horse my kingdom for a horse"  How many times have I thought when dealing with SF "SQL, SQL my project for SQL."
